# Show the inequality $(n+1)^z-n^z \geq n^{z-1}(z-1)$ for $n, z \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

How can I show that the inequality $(n+1)^z-n^z \geq n^{z-1}(z-1)$ for $n, z \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ always holds? Since $z$ is not a natural number we can not use the Binomial Theorem, otherwise this would be trivial.

Comment: Did you know that there is a version of the Binomial Theorem where the exponent doesn't have to be an integer? Isaac Newton showed that the exponent can be any real number and you may use an infinite series rather than a terminating series: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton's_generalized_binomial_theorem  \begin{align}
   (x+y)^r & =\sum_{k=0}^\infty {r \choose k} x^{r-k} y^k \\
   &= x^r + r x^{r-1} y + \frac{r(r-1)}{2!} x^{r-2} y^2 + \frac{r(r-1)(r-2)}{3!} x^{r-3} y^3 + \cdots.
 \end{align}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you would just use the Bernoulli's inequality:

$$\left(1+\frac 1n\right)^z - 1\geq 1+\frac zn - 1 = \frac zn > \frac{z-1}{n}$$

**EDIT:**

The above works when $z\leq 1$ when $z\in\mathbb{R}.$ When $z<1$, RHS is negative so the inequality is trivial.

Comment: It works for $z\ge 1$, right? (for $0 < z < 1$, the inequality is obvious)

Comment: @River Li you are right I was too lazy to write that detail. Besides, knowing the Taylor Expansion mentioned in the comment is more general and more helpful than Bernoulli's anyway.